# с помощью чекбокса отправить запросы в бд, передавая массив значений

Tags: php

Делаю личную интеграцию под биржу криптовалют. У меня есть список ВОЗМОЖНЫХ ставок (ордеров), каждая их которых оформлена как form, передающая в input'ах данные для создания ордеров:

```
            <form action="order_creat.php" method="post" target="_blank" title="Покупаем крипту дешевле. Наращивается <?=$uah;?>. SHORT.">
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="s" value="<?=$b;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="7" name="quantity" value="<?= number_format($b_koll,8, '.', '');?>" class="colortext">
                        <input type="text" size="1" name="kripta" value="<?= $eth;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="4" name="oncost" value="<?= $per_cost;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="10" name="price" value="<?= number_format($b_cost,8, '.', '');?>" class="colortext">
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="on_summ" value="<?= $on_summ;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="8" name="summ" value="<?= number_format($b_summ,7, '.', '');?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="block" value="<?='+'. number_format($profit,2, '.', ' ').$uah;?>">
                        <input type="text" size="1" name="block_id" value="1">

                        <input type="hidden" name="order_status" value="<?=$order_status_cr;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pair" value="<?=$eth_uah;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?=$b_type;?>">
                        <!--input type="submit" value="Создать ордер! +UAH"-->
                        <?resolution_sell(number_format($b_summ,7, '.', ''), $b);?>
                    </form>
                    <form action="order_creat.php" method="post" target="_blank" title="Покупаем валюту дешевле. Наращивается <?=$eth;?>. SHORT.">
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="s" value="<?= $b;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="7" name="quantity" value="<?= number_format($bkk_koll,6, '.', '');?>" class="colortext">
                        <input type="text" size="1" name="kripta" value="<?= $eth;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="4" name="oncost" value="<?= $per_cost;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="10" name="price" value="<?= number_format($bkk_cost,8, '.', '');?>" class="colortext">
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="on_summ" value="<?= $on_summ;?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="8" name="summ" value="<?= number_format($bkk_summ,7, '.', '');?>" readonly>
                        <input type="text" size="5" name="block" value="<?='+'. number_format($bkk_profit,6, '.', ' ').$eth;?>">
                        <input type="text" size="1" name="block_id" value="1">

                        <input type="hidden" name="order_status" value="<?=$order_status_cr;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pair" value="<?=$eth_uah;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?=$b_type;?>">
                        <!--input type="submit" value="Создать ордер! +ETH"-->
                        <?resolution_sell(number_format($bkk_summ,7, '.', ''), $b);
                        echo $b_komis_str .' - '. number_format($b_komis,6, '.', ' ') . $eth;
                        ?>
                    </form>
```

возле каждой такой ВОЗМОЖНОЙ ставки есть кнопка "Создать ордер", которая передаёт по api на биржу данные для создания ордера:
pair - валютная пара
quantity - кол-во по ордеру
price - цена по ордеру
type - тип ордера, может принимать следующие значения:
+ некоторые данные для записи мне в базу.

Задача следующая: я хочу сделать так, чтоб не нажимать возле каждой ставки "Создать ордер", а отметить их чекбоксами и один раз нажав "создать ордера" отправить эти все данные. Я знаю, что через чек-боксы можно передавать данные в массиве, но они передаются из одного поля. А у меня полей много. Можно ли это решить? Спасибо.

Comment: Передавайте двухмерным массивом, если много полей

Comment: это мне понятно. Мне не понятно как собрать из разных input'ов в один массив эти поля и их значения

Comment: @Oughtem, 1. В вашем коде используются разные формы и нужно понимать, что в рамках одной формы поля со значениями другой формы не передаются.
2. Можете создать одну форму и называть поля с каким-то суффиксом или префиксом, например, <input name="eth_s" ... /><input name ="eth_price" ...> и потом на стороне сервера парсить получаемые данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $countOfCurrencies = 2; // количество предполагаемых данных (форм)
    if ( isset($_POST) && count($_POST) != 0 ){
        for ($i=0; $i < $countOfCurrencies; $i++) { 
            if ( isset($_POST['cur_'][$i]['check']) && $_POST['cur_'][$i]['check']=='on' ){
                // обработка отправленной пары (пример)

                $data = new array();
                $data[0] = $_POST['item'][$i][0];
                $data[1] = $_POST['item'][$i][1];
                $data[2] = $_POST['item'][$i][2];
                $db->insert($data);
                unset($data);               
            }
        }
    }
?>

<form action="?" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cur_[0][check]">Валюта 1<br />
    <input type=text name="item[0][0]"><br />
    <input type=text name="item[0][1]"><br />
    <input type=text name="item[0][2]"><br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="cur_[1][check]">Валюта 2<br />
    <input type=text name="item[1][0]"><br />
    <input type=text name="item[1][1]"><br />
    <input type=text name="item[1][2]"><br />
    <!-- ... //-->
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="создать ордера" />
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Конструкция 
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[1][chek]">Валюта 2<br />
    <input type=text name="item[1][val]">
это решение данного вопроса!